# Creating a table in mysql using a list of names

Tags: peewee

How can I create a function in python that takes a list of names and that function creates tables in mysql with those names using peewee in python?

```
import peewee 


table_names = ['table1', 'table2', 'table2']
data = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']

def table_creator(table_name, data):
    #create tables in myql and save data.
    pass
```